# Parse Ionic App auto push notification possibilities

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, parse-platform

I'm makin this cordova/ionic project in which I'm using Parse for the backend.
I want users to be able to send a message to other users. When doing so, a push notification should appear at the receiver's device.

This should work cross Android and iOS.

Would this be possible using only Ionic and Parse?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out on IOS? The below answer with suggested plugin are android only.

Comment: do you get iOS to work with Parse  + Cordova?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar project.

Below are some steps to get basic Idea

a. Register to [Parse.com](https://parse.com/)

b. For building with project with Ionic you'll need a JS plugin for accessing Parse Components. Use this [GitHub Plugin](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin)

c. Copy paste the below code in `ionicPlatformReady()` in `app.js`

```
// You'll get the appId and Clinet Key from Parse.com
parsePlugin.initialize(appId, clientKey, function() {

parsePlugin.subscribe('SampleChannel', function() {

    parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) {

        /**
         * Now you can construct an object and save it to your own services, or Parse, and corrilate users to parse installations
         * 
         var install_data = {
            installation_id: id,
            channels: ['SampleChannel']
         }
         *
         */

    }, function(e) {
        alert('error');
    });

}, function(e) {
    alert('error');
});

}, function(e) {
alert('error');
});
```

d. From the Parse account dashboard, send a push notification for testing and you should be able to see it.

**Note**

It is very likely that you may get error saying `Reference to  parsePlugin not defined.` which means the cordova plugin is not getting loaded while execution.

I hope it helps. All the best.

Thanks,

Comment: ¿How can you do something when receiving the notification? There is no way to trigger an event when you press on the notification or get it into your app to trigger something.

Comment: by default the Parse notification will simply open the app.. if you want a custom behavior you can implement a Custom broadcast receiver and then handle it

Comment: [FrostyElk/cordova-parse-plugin](https://github.com/FrostyElk/cordova-parse-plugin) provides functionality for sending the push notification data into your javascript layer. Have a look at `getPendingPush()` defined in `ParsePlugin.js`. (for Cordova 5 support, check my fork of the project at [mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler](https://github.com/mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler))